Anatase band path not correct (GPAW)
I am calculating the band structure of anatase, but my code does not provide the correct band path for the band structure. Therefore, the FBZ is also not correct.

calc = GPAW('groundstate.anatase.gpw')
atoms = calc.get_atoms()
path = atoms.cell.bandpath(density=7)
path.write('path.anatase.json')

calc = calc.fixed_density(kpts=path, symmetry='off')

bs = calc.band_structure()
bs.write('bs.anatase.json')

Thank you for helping!
Best regards
